# Is it possible to bypass an Email Provider's verifyRequest page?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

My project contains next-auth pages config for custom `verifyRequest` pages, amongst others:

```
pages: {
    error: "/auth/error-page",
    signIn: "/auth/sign-in",
    verifyRequest: "/auth/check-email",
  },
```

I am working on a signup redesign that includes a "verify request page" in a SPA, therefore negating the need for a `verifyRequest` altogether.

While rolling out the new redesign, I want to maintain the `verifyRequest` for the old signup workflow.

However, both designs are implemented with a client-side use of next-auth's `signIn` function, which attempts to redirect to the configured `verifyRequest` by default.

Is there any way to disable the `verifyRequest` or to intercept the redirect `signIn` attempts to invoke?

So far I've used `window.onbeforeunload` as a means to intercept, but I am hoping for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the docs:
https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#using-the-redirect-false-option

> In some cases, you might want to deal with the sign in response on the same page and disable the default redirection. For example, if an error occurs (like wrong credentials given by the user), you might want to handle the error on the same page. For that, you can pass redirect: false in the second parameter object.

> e.g.

> `signIn('credentials', { redirect: false, password: 'password' })`
> `signIn('email', { redirect: false, email: 'bill@fillmurray.com' })`